# Хеширование строки в Python SHA3-256

Tags: python-3.x, строки, хеширование

Есть скрипт, он хеширует данные 256 файлов. Далее **добавляет строки в список, сортирует их по возрастанию и склеивает в одну длинную строку**. После необходимо **приклеить свою почту к этой длинной строке и полученный результат ещё раз хешировать** и в итоге получить **одну хешированную 64-значную строку**.

```
import glob
import hashlib

filenames = glob.glob("E:/task2/*.data")
items = []
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
        digest = hashlib.sha3_256(data).hexdigest()
        items.append(digest)
res = "".join(sorted(items))

string = "example@gmail.com"
print(res + string)
```

Но данный код при конкатенации строк **не добавляет строку**, или добавляет но в виде рандомных символов. Как можно эти строки конкатенировать и хешировать?

Answer (score 0):

```
import hashlib
import os
hash_list=[]
path_of_the_directory= r"C:\Users\files"
for filename in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
    file = os.path.join(path_of_the_directory,filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        with open(file,"rb") as f:
            bytes=f.read()
            readeble_hash=hashlib.sha3_256(bytes).hexdigest()
            hash_list.append(readeble_hash)
hash_list.sort()
hash_list.append("some@mail.sd")
list_to_str=''.join([str(elem) for elem in hash_list])
res=hashlib.sha3_256(list_to_str.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]